# Linestring end coordinates in a .csv file along with source and target id

Tags: pandas, dataframe, geopandas, shapely, multilinestring

I have a Digital Road Map dataset containing coordinates of nodes interconnected through road network and Node number.
[Dataset in xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkSST.png)
Dataset has three columns : Col1-**source **, Colm 2 **Target** and Column 3- **geometry**. geometry is a linestring of road having start point coordinate, an end point coordinate and few intermediate point coordinates. **Source** and **Target** columns are Node number of starting node and end node of each road network.
I want to extract only coordinate of starting node and end node from each row. Then arrange the filtered dataset such that each source and each target has the respective coordinates beside it.
The sample output file is
[desired sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhifH.png)

I am looking for code in shapely, most of the info is on one linestring. Since my data has more than a million rows so I am not able to find a relevant code that iterates through entire dataset.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking.  It looks like you want to extract source and target from the string geometry.  But from the picture, it's not clear how source and target contained within geometry.  What exact are you wanting to achieve and what is the expected output for a given input?

Comment: @brb Thanks for your comment. The raw data is a detail about network of roads in form of Digital Road Map of one city. In each which each road has an starting coordinate, an end coordinate and few intermediate coordinate. I want to filter the data in a way that I extract only starting coordinate and end coordinate.(I will update my question with a different image set)

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  If geometry contains two coordinates, separated by a comma, and you want to assign to variables source and target, the solution by cookie below will work.  Just stripe 'LINESTRING', '(' and ')' from geometry and split on ','.  Then assign to source and target instead of Start and end, and you are fine.  But if the imagine gives the expected output, it is not clear how source and target relate at all to geometry.  For example, how to do you source= 67173 and target= 67196 from geometry= LINESTRING(139.9164... 36.6825... , 139.9164... 36.6822...)?

Comment: If the solution below is not the answer, then you need to give a single input and explain what output you want from it and how those outputs are derived.

Comment: thanks again. @brb thanks again. Meanwhile I tried this and got the endpoints from Linestring    :             'code' for i, row in nodes_raw.iterrows():
#     print(type(row['geometry']))
    line = shapely.wkt.loads(row['geometry'])
#     print(type(line))
    endpoints = line.boundary
    print(row['source'], '\t', row['target'], '\t', endpoints)
    if i > 100:
        break  <br/> It worked so far .

Comment: you are making question very difficult to answer by posting your data such that it has to go through OCR before it can be used in an answer....  include as markdown in question

Answer (score 1):

- your sample data is unusable as it is an image.  Have simulated some
- pick first and last point from *LINESTRING*
- structure as columns (in `df`)
- reshape `df` as `df2` as your desired structure

```
import io
import shapely.geometry, shapely.wkt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data...
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        '''source,target,geometry
0,100,"LINESTRING (5.897759230176348 49.44266714130711, 6.242751092156993 49.90222565367873, 5.674051954784829 49.5294835475575)"
1,101,"LINESTRING (13.59594567226444 48.87717194273715, 12.51844038254671 54.470370591848, 6.658229607783568 49.20195831969157)"
2,102,"LINESTRING (16.71947594571444 50.21574656839354, 23.42650841644439 50.30850576435745, 22.77641889821263 49.02739533140962, 14.60709842291953 51.74518809671997)"
3,103,"LINESTRING (18.62085859546164 54.68260569927078, 23.79919884613338 52.69109935160657, 20.89224450041863 54.31252492941253)"
4,104,"LINESTRING (5.606975945670001 51.03729848896978, 6.589396599970826 51.85202912048339, 3.31501148496416 51.34577662473805, 5.988658074577813 51.85161570902505)"
5,105,"LINESTRING (4.799221632515724 49.98537303323637, 6.043073357781111 50.12805166279423, 3.31501148496416 51.34577662473805, 6.15665815595878 50.80372101501058, 3.314971144228537 51.34575511331991)"
6,106,"LINESTRING (3.31501148496416 51.34577662473805, 3.830288527043137 51.62054454203195, 6.905139601274129 53.48216217713065, 4.705997348661185 53.09179840759776)"
7,107,"LINESTRING (7.092053256873896 53.14404328064489, 3.830288527043137 51.62054454203195, 6.842869500362383 52.22844025329755, 3.31501148496416 51.34577662473805)"
8,108,"LINESTRING (6.589396599970826 51.85202912048339, 6.905139601274129 53.48216217713065, 3.314971144228537 51.34575511331991, 5.988658074577813 51.85161570902505)"
9,109,"LINESTRING (5.606975945670001 51.03729848896978, 4.286022983425084 49.90749664977255)"'''
    )
)

# pick first and last point from each linestring as columns
df = df.join(
    df["geometry"]
    .apply(lambda ls: np.array(shapely.wkt.loads(ls).coords)[[0, -1]])
    .apply(
        lambda x: {
            f"{c}_point": shapely.geometry.Point(x[i])
            for i, c in enumerate(df.columns)
            if c != "geometry"
        }
    )
    .apply(pd.Series)
)

# reshape to row wise
df2 = pd.melt(
    df,
    id_vars=["source", "target"],
    value_vars=["source_point", "target_point"],
    value_name="point",
)
df2["node_number"] = np.where(
    df2["variable"] == "source_point", df2["source"], df2["target"]
)
df2 = df2.drop(columns=["source", "target", "variable"])
```

#### output

| point | node_number |
| --- | --- |
| POINT (5.897759230176348 49.44266714130711) | 0 |
| POINT (13.59594567226444 48.87717194273715) | 1 |
| POINT (16.71947594571444 50.21574656839354) | 2 |
| POINT (18.62085859546164 54.68260569927078) | 3 |
| POINT (5.606975945670001 51.03729848896978) | 4 |
| POINT (4.799221632515724 49.98537303323637) | 5 |
| POINT (3.31501148496416 51.34577662473805) | 6 |
| POINT (7.092053256873896 53.14404328064489) | 7 |
| POINT (6.589396599970826 51.85202912048339) | 8 |
| POINT (5.606975945670001 51.03729848896978) | 9 |
| POINT (5.674051954784829 49.5294835475575) | 100 |
| POINT (6.658229607783568 49.20195831969157) | 101 |
| POINT (14.60709842291953 51.74518809671997) | 102 |
| POINT (20.89224450041863 54.31252492941253) | 103 |
| POINT (5.988658074577813 51.85161570902505) | 104 |
| POINT (3.314971144228537 51.34575511331991) | 105 |
| POINT (4.705997348661185 53.09179840759776) | 106 |
| POINT (3.31501148496416 51.34577662473805) | 107 |
| POINT (5.988658074577813 51.85161570902505) | 108 |
| POINT (4.286022983425084 49.90749664977255) | 109 |

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
df[['Start', 'end']] = df['geometry'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this earlier to split the data. But it helped only in splitting the values in cells of column 'geometry'. I have to arrange the data in such a way that 'Source' gets the first coordinate and 'Target' gets the last coordinate.